# Excel Connections in Google Drive

Tags: excel, connection, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have an Excel 2010 file (.xlsx) with multiple connections to import data from the web. Instead of having to open the file manually and click "Refresh All", I want to use Google Docs (specifically Google Sheets) to automate the refresh process every 60 minutes. I uploaded the xlsx file to my Google Drive but the connections do not work anymore. How do I get around this?

Additional information:
1. The data connections are to Kayak flight search service. Here's an example [page](http://www.kayak.com/flights/JFK-CDG/2014-12-16-flexible/2015-01-14-flexible). I am importing the table data at the top of the page which shows prices for flexible dates.
2. I tried using [IMPORTHTML](http://www.labnol.org/internet/import-html-in-google-docs/28125/) in Google Sheets but for some reason it doesn't identify the above table as an HTML table. I get a parse error.

Comment: Using `=ImportHTML("http://www.kayak.com/flights/JFK-CDG/2014-12-16-flexible/2015-01-14-flexible", "table", 2)` in Google Sheets does not give me a parse error, but I do not see prices anyway. It may be that kayak is preventing such queries.

Comment: That didn't work for me. The cell says "Loading..." and then changes to #N/A. When I hover over the cell I see "Error: Imported content is empty."

Comment: Its definitely not Kayak preventing the queries. Because I am able to do it in excel as stated in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Kimono](http://www.kimonolabs.com/) to generate this [API](https://www.kimonolabs.com/apis/ccyfjzlm) (you have to sign up to use it) which can return CSV of the form:

```
"collection1"
"depart-sat.text","depart-sat.href"
"$798","javascript: FilterList.flexFilterToDates('20141213', '20150111', 798)"
"$798","javascript: FilterList.flexFilterToDates('20141213', '20150112', 798)"
...

"collection2"
"depart-sun.text","depart-sun.href"
"$1127","javascript: FilterList.flexFilterToDates('20141214', '20150111', 1127)"
"$1211","javascript: FilterList.flexFilterToDates('20141214', '20150112', 1211)"
...
```

In Google Spreadsheet you can get the data with `=ImportDATA("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/csv/ccyfjzlm?apikey=YOURAPIKEY")`.